# How to play audio file(.raw) in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, web, dart, flutter-web

I'm working on flutter-web where I would like to play the audio on the web, From the server, I will get .raw file.

File encode info: Sample rate: 16 khz, pcm mono channel

I have tried the following plugins: [audioplayer_web](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/audioplayer_web), [soundpool](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/soundpool#-example-tab-)

While trying to play .raw file from the asset for demo purpose getting following error:

```
DOMException: Unable to decode audio dataError: EncodingError: Unable to decode audio data
```

**Can anyone suggest how to play .raw file or anyway to achieve?**
Any help will be appreciated.

[file detai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yt1H.png)

Comment: Do you know what sample rate, bit depth, format (floats, signed ints) the audio is encoded in?

Comment: Sample rate: 16 khz, pcm mono channel

Comment: The simplest thing is probably to prepend a wav file header to the samples, where you can specify the missing information. Alternatively you could feed the raw samples to the sound card. Check out my audio_worklet repo on GitHub.

Comment: Can you please share the repo link? also you refer this to get more detail about file https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yt1H.png

Comment: I was trying to convert .raw to .wav but which is not possible as to write file somewhere require path and I don't have an idea how to provide a path for web and available plugins are not supported for the web.

Comment: Here's the repo: https://github.com/richardheap/audio_worklet Note - it's iOS and Android only, but feel free to add web support - it was all designed around the web audio API for exactly that reason. Wouldn't it be easier to have the web *server* add the WAV header on the fly as it serves the audio?